# MongoDB Textsearch manipulation textSearch

Tags: mongodb

I have a text search in MongoDB 3.4 like the following:

```
db.products.find({
    $text : {
        $search: '"harry potter 3"' 
    }
}, {
    score: {
        "$meta": "textScore"
    },
    name: 1,
    author_name: 1,
}).sort({
    score: {
        "$meta": "textScore"
    },
    name: 1
}).limit(9);
```

The query works as expected.

**A sample document is:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("597f17d22be7925d9a056e82"), 
    "name" : "My cool title", 
    "author_name" : "Doe, John",
    "language" : "german",
    "keywords" : ["harry potter", "keyword 2", "keyword 3"],
    ...
}
```

The textsearch index is on name, keywords and author_name.

**The problem:**

Since I have a german speaking webshop, I wanna prioritize docs in german (language = german). If you search for "harry potter 3" i get first the turkish, english and polish version (because of higher score, because they have the word "harry potter" twice in title [don't know why]).

So how to get a higher sort placement for the german versions of the books?

Just to add a filter with {"language": "german"} is not an option, since I want to show the other results as well.

**Idea which do not work**

The best thing would be to find a way to increase the "score" of the german books, but I dont know how. Something like this (this dont work of course):

Add a field language_score to every document and give all german docs a language_score=5, all english books language_score=2 and all others language_score=0 and then do the sorting this way:

```
{
    score: {
        "$sum" {
            "$meta": "textScore",
            "language_score": "language_score"
        }
    },
    name: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the aggregation framework you can achieve what you need. The following query is untested because of my lack of sample data and index setup but you get the idea:

```
db.products.aggregate // note that we're using .aggregate() now instead of find()
(
  {
    $match: // that is the equivalent of your find() filter
    {
      $text:
      {
        $search: '"harry potter 3"' 
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:
    {
      "languageScore": // here we magically compute our weight
      {
        $cond:
        {
          if: { $eq: [ "$language", "german" ] },
          then: "5",
          else:
          {
            $cond:
            {
              if: { $eq: [ "$language", "english" ] },
              then: "2",
              else: 0
            }
          }
        }
      },
      score:
      {
        "$meta": "textScore"
      },
      name: 1,
      author_name: 1,
    }
  },
  {
    $sort:
    {
      languageScore: -1, // and then we can sort by that score
      score: {
        "$meta": "textScore"
      },
      name: 1
    }
  },
  { $limit: 9 }
)
```